# When I use dagger in my kotlin project, I get an error

Tags: dagger-2

Suddenly I started getting this error, and I don't understand why. If anyone could just let me know where the error lies, that would be great.

This problem occurs when i use dagger implementation when i comment below lines my code is working please let me know what i am doing wrong

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

1.implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.47")
2.kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler::2.47")

Here my build.gradle

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
namespace 'com.example.testproject'
compileSdk 34

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.testproject"
    minSdk 24
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true

}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.1.1'

implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.47")
kapt ("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.47")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As in the [GitHub README.md](https://github.com/google/dagger#gradle), your `implementation` line should specify `com.google.dagger:dagger`, not `com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler`.

```
/* BAD  */ implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.47"
/* GOOD */ implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.47"

/* GOOD */ kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.47"
```